# what is the differences between that line in oracle ERD?

Tags: sql, oracle, erd

What is the differences between that relationship lines in oracle ERD?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several notations to represent an entity-relationship model. The one you are looking at is called [Barker's notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barker%27s_notation) where the relationship(line) is divided into two halves. Each half can be either solid (relationship is mandatory) or dashed (relationship is optional) and you can read those relationships as follows:

1. Solid half and solid half  - relationship is mandatory.

   *Each computer **must** have a hard drive, and one hard drive **must** be installed into one computer.*
2. Dashed half and solid half - relationship is mandatory on the right and optional on the left:

   *Each computer **must** have a hard drive, and one hard drive **may or may not** be installed into one computer. (will be vise verse if right side of the relationship is dashed and the left one is solid )*
3. Dashed half and dashed half - relationship is optional.

   *Each computer **may or may not** have a hard drive, and one hard drive **may or may not** be installed into one computer.*

Same goes for one to many and many to many relationships.

Answer (score 5):

Dashed line indicates minimum cardinality of relation can be zero, continuos line indicates minimum cardinality of relation is at least one.

Show this [interesting](http://www.informatik.uni-giessen.de/staff/brass/dd02/c2_deser.pdf) document

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: @DudiBoy: This link in 2013 was visible, now you must have credential to access. I don't know how find a new link